# MongoDb LIKE on two fields combined with AND

Tags: php, mongodb, sql-like

I'm looking for MySQL's equivalent of

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 LIKE '%somestring%' AND field2 LIKE '%anotherstring%'
```

I did try a couple of things, including

```
'field1' => '/somestring/i', 'field2' => '/anotherstring/i'
```

I'm getting no results back, or just data based upon one of the two fields. Is this not possible in MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 db.collection.find({field1: {$regex: /somestring/i}, field2: {$regex: /anotherstring/i}});
```

In `php` you should do by `MongoRegex`.

```
array(field1 => new MongoRegex("/somestring/i"), field2 => new MongoRegex("/anotherstring/i"))
```

Comment: I am glad if I was able to help :)